# How can I store and access matrix elements in gnuplot?

Tags: matrix, gnuplot, call, store

I'm trying to make 19x19 hexagonal lattice and each lattice contains a cylinder with different colors described as 'hexagon.dat'.

2-> Cylinder colored with red

1-> Cylinder colored with green

hexagon.dat

```
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

But currently, since I don't know how to store and access the matrix data of hexagon.dat, There are only green cylinders
This is my script for gnuplot

script

```
set term X11 persist title "test" size 1000, 1000

P = 0.78
pin_id = 0

do for [pin_ix=-9:9]{
do for [pin_iy=-9:9]{

cx = pin_ix*P + pin_iy*(-P/2)
cy = pin_iy*sqrt(3)/2*P
pin_id = pin_id + 1
set object pin_id poly from cx-P/2, cy+P/2/sqrt(3) \
                       to cx, cy+P/sqrt(3) \
                       to cx+P/2, cy+P/2/sqrt(3) \
                       to cx+P/2, cy-P/2/sqrt(3) \
                       to cx, cy-P/sqrt(3) \
                       to cx-P/2, cy-P/2/sqrt(3) \
                       to cx-P/2, cy+P/2/sqrt(3) \
fs solid fc rgb "red"


pin_id = pin_id + 1
set object pin_id circle at cx, cy size 0.3275 \
fs solid fc rgb "green"
}
}

set size ratio 1.0
set xr [-11:11]
set yr [-11:11]


plot 1/0
```

I'm waiting for your helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `plot ... with circles` to plot the cylinders. Then you can select the color with `lc variable`:

```
P = 0.78
pin_id = 0

do for [pin_ix=-9:9]{
do for [pin_iy=-9:9]{

cx = pin_ix*P + pin_iy*(-P/2)
cy = pin_iy*sqrt(3)/2*P
pin_id = pin_id + 1
set object pin_id poly from cx-P/2, cy+P/2/sqrt(3) \
                       to cx, cy+P/sqrt(3) \
                       to cx+P/2, cy+P/2/sqrt(3) \
                       to cx+P/2, cy-P/2/sqrt(3) \
                       to cx, cy-P/sqrt(3) \
                       to cx-P/2, cy-P/2/sqrt(3) \
                       to cx-P/2, cy+P/2/sqrt(3) \
fs solid fc rgb "red"


pin_id = pin_id + 1
}
}

set size ratio 1.0
set xr [-11:11]
set yr [-11:11]

set style fill solid noborder
set linetype 1 lc rgb 'red'
set linetype 2 lc rgb 'green'
plot 'hexagon.dat' matrix using (($1-9)*P + ($2-9)*(-P/2)):(($2-9)*sqrt(3)/2 * P):(0.3275):3 with circles lc variable
```

[image]

With version 5.0 you could use `stats` to extract the matrix dimension:

```
stats 'hexagon.dat' matrix
N = int(STATS_size_x)
do for [pin_ix=-(N/2):((N-1)/2)] {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

NewHexData

```
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

script

```
set term X11 persist title "test" size 1000, 1000
P = 0.78
pin_id = 0

do for [pin_ix=-9:9]{
do for [pin_iy=-9:9]{

cx = pin_ix*P + pin_iy*(-P/2)
cy = pin_iy*sqrt(3)/2*P
pin_id = pin_id + 1
set object pin_id poly from cx-P/2, cy+P/2/sqrt(3) \
                       to cx, cy+P/sqrt(3) \
                       to cx+P/2, cy+P/2/sqrt(3) \
                       to cx+P/2, cy-P/2/sqrt(3) \
                       to cx, cy-P/sqrt(3) \
                       to cx-P/2, cy-P/2/sqrt(3) \
                       to cx-P/2, cy+P/2/sqrt(3) \
fs solid fc rgb "red"


pin_id = pin_id + 1
}
}

set size ratio 1.0
set xr [-11:11]
set yr [-11:11]

set style fill solid noborder
set linetype 1 lc rgb 'green'
set linetype 2 lc rgb 'red'
plot 'NewHexData' matrix using (($1-9)*P + ($2-9)*(-P/2)):(($2-9)*sqrt(3)/2 * P):(0.3275):3 with circles lc variable
```

Since I don't have enough reputation, I cannot upload the resulting image.
Anyway I got this figure.

http://imgur.com/vEpjdll

I really thank you to Christoph!